# Show HTML Code for dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

is there a way to retrieve the html code that is generated when dynamically creating a table using v-for loops in vue.

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="99">row 1</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">row 2</th>
        <th colspan="99">row 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td v-for="index in numOfCLO" v-bind:key="index">{{index}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="index in numOfMod" v-bind:key="index">
          <td >row 3 {{index}}</td>
          <td v-for="index in numOfCLO" v-bind:key="index"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

For example, If I were to enter a 3 for the NumOfCLO variable, the html would be something like

```html
      <tr>
          <td>{{index}}</td>
          <td>{{index}}</td>
          <td>{{index}}</td>
      </tr>
```

instead of

```html
<tr>
          <td v-for="index in numOfCLO" v-bind:key="index">{{index}}</td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: What do you mean with `retrieve the html code`?

Comment: I want to create a dynamic table form, that allows the user to create the table with the amount of rows/columns they want. Then I want to save the html code to the database. What i mean by retrieve the html code is something like this: https://tiptap.dev/export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes (sort of), you could assign the table element to a [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) and retrieve its `outerHTML`. Note however that,

> ...about the ref registration timing: because the refs themselves are created as a result of the render function, you cannot access them on the initial render - they don’t exist yet! `$refs` is also non-reactive, therefore you should not attempt to use it in templates for data-binding.

Therefore, if you somehow need it to react to the input changes (like doing "live" preview), you could either generate the HTML on-demand (with a button click, like the following example) or [`watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) the form inputs for changes and (re)generate.

(This example uses an HTML formatter called [`js-beautify`](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify). Please remove it if you don't need one)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: () => ({
    numOfCLO: 3,
    numOfMod: 5,
    generatedHtml: ''
  }),

  mounted() {
    this.generate();
  },

  methods: {
    generate() {
      this.generatedHtml = html_beautify(this.$refs.table.outerHTML);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container input {
  width: 40px;
}
.container > * {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.13.0/beautify-html.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <input v-model.number="numOfCLO" type="number" placeholder="number of CLO" />
    <input v-model.number="numOfMod" type="number" placeholder="number of Mod" />
    <button @click="generate">Generate HTML</button>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <table ref="table">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="99">row 1</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">row 2</th>
        <th colspan="99">row 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td v-for="index in numOfCLO" v-bind:key="index">{{index}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="index in numOfMod" v-bind:key="index">
        <td>row 3 {{index}}</td>
        <td v-for="index in numOfCLO" v-bind:key="index"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <textarea cols="40" rows="10">{{generatedHtml}}</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```